# how to get errors and line number from php file without running?

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to read line by line from a index.php file and want to display the error and line number of error.This is what i have tried

```
$code_to_check = "$name = 'soubhagya';echo $name";
$result = eval($code_to_check);
```

the above coding is not working because i put $ symbol in a variable

Comment: Change it to:

    `$code_to_check = $name." = 'soubhagya';echo ".$name;`

Comment: no you are taking it wrong .here i want a variable which will hold the entire php code from file.suppose index.php has 500 lines of code , i just want to check line by line and find out the error as well as line of error ..if you have any other solution then you can provide

Answer (score 0):

This is going to solve your problem

```
$file = 'file.php';
$searchforError = 'content';

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchforError, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
    echo "Found error:\n";
    echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
    $charpos = strpos($contents, implode("\n", $matches[0]));
    list($before) = str_split($contents, $charpos);
    $line_number = strlen($before) - strlen(str_replace("\n", "", $before)) + 1;
    echo 'on line '.$line_number;
}
else{
   echo "No errors found";
}
```

Comment: its not working can you do one thing for me just replace $ with \$ from a string.my topic is to find out error from php file